# python match values from javascript using re.search

Tags: python

Helloo guys,

I want to extract two values from one javascript but my code not working.

Content :

```
window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {
        GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.3750694379,
        GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.309934898
    };
```

My code :

```
sk = re.search(r'window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {(.*?)', str(content)).group(1)
print(sk)
```

But it prints nothing !!

I need to get longitude and latitiude into variable, how i can do that ?

Comment: What are your trying to match? You might be looking for the `dotall` flag.

Comment: 55.3750694379 and 25.309934898

Comment: i need to match longitude and latitude

Comment: How is `content` actually defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will extract the longitude and latitude numbers into a list.

```
import re
content = """window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {
                GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.3750694379,
                GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.309934898
            };"""

lat_lon_re = re.compile(r'GOOGLE_MAPS_L.+:\s+([-\d\.]+)')

m = lat_lon_re.findall(content)
print(m)

Output:
['55.3750694379', '25.309934898']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(\w+):\s+([\d.]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/a9bn3A/1/).

Comment: sk = re.search(r'window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {(\w+):\s+([\d.]+)', str(content)).group(2)

Comment: @guruji2020: without the `window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {` part.